# How do i add a Joda DateTime Object into my MSSQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime

so i have a mssql database with a DateObjectCreated column of type DateTime. The values it will accept into the table are in the format 2013-12-23 12:23:56.567. However, my java program is creating a joda DateTime object with the format 2013-12-23T 12:23:56.567Z. this wont insert into my db. i need to either convert "2013-12-23T 12:23:56.567Z" to 2013-12-23 12:23:56.567 or find a way to allow my db table to accept "2013-12-23T 12:23:56.567Z" format
any help on this matter will be much appreciated
Many thanks 
Billy
Controller

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);//this gives me the string as i need it 
DateTime dt = new DateTime(formattedDate);//here it adds the 'T' and 'Z'
```

ive  tried

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);//this gives me the string as i need it 
Date dt = formatter.parse(formattedDate);//here it gives me the same as new Date()
```

Comment: Are you using JPA? Plain jdbc? can you show some code? What have you tried?

Comment: Can't you get time in milliseconds from JodaTime and create a Timestamp to pass to MySQL?

Comment: No need to deal with milliseconds. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20489126/642706).

Answer (score 0):

1. DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);

2.[enter link description here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_date.htm)
    The TO_DATE function can be used in Oracle/PLSQL. For example:

TO_DATE('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  would return a date value of July 9, 2003

TO_DATE('070903', 'MMDDYY')  would return a date value of July 9, 2003

TO_DATE('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')     would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002

Comment: Hi, Sorry to be a pain but i am trying to insert some values into a database via a java controller class. the table already exists and the conversion needs to be done in the controller before i insert the values. can you give me an example of the code you would use to achieve this from my controller. Many thanks. Billy

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience ,i am checking on it

Answer (score 0):

Your DB column has a DateTime type. The text representation of your date is irrelevant for persisting it.
Regardless of the API you are using (JDBC, JPA, Hibernate) there will be something like a "setDateTime(Date date)" method that allows you to pass in a java.util.Date or java.sql.Date or a Java long. You can use the milli-second value of your Joda DateTime object to create whatever is required by the API.

Answer (score 0):

You are working way too hard.

1. Convert your [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object to a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Just call [`toDate()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate()) method.
2. Pass Date instance to your framework or SQL.

The [answer by Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473283/642706) is correct in its first part, but is wrong in the end in that you need not deal with milliseconds. Joda-Time knows how to convert to java.util.Date.

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
java.util.Date nowAsJavaUtilDate = now.toDate();
```

---

By the way, the [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class is simply a very thin subclass of java.util.Date. So don't let that throw you.

---

In the future, this will become even easier. Java 8 brings the new JSR 310 classes in the java.time.* package. These classes supplant the mess that is java.util.Date/Calendar. They are inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected. As they are a built-in part of Java, expect JDBC and related frameworks to be updated to handle these new types directly.